# Backbone Marionette ItemView return html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, marionette

I want to render marionette ItemView and append result html() to my div.
My code:

```
 var ProjectItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#ProjectItem",
        tagName: 'div',
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on('change', this.life, this);
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    life: function () {
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.model));
    }
});


var tmp = new Project({project_id: 1});
tmp.fetch();

$('#container').append(new ProjectItemView({model: tmp}).$el);
```

alert in `life: function` shows model right. It means fetch works fine.
**The question is - how to get html as result of view.**
I also tried `$('#container').append(new ProjectItemView({model: tmp}).render().el)`;

**The problem was with the REST service that I use to populate collections/models. It returns array that contains one element - not plain object directly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to react to `render` event from marionette.

```
...
onRender : function() {
  $('#container').append(this.$el);
}
...
new ProjectItemView({model: tmp});
tmp.fetch();
```

If you want to get uncoupled, fire a distinct app event from within your view handler to the outside world. [Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio) might be worth considering if you're not already.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is only the order of operations. Try this:

```
$('#container').append((new ProjectItemView({model: tmp})).render().el);
```

The way you had it before, you were invoking `.render()` on the constructor. With the extra parenthesis above, `.render()` is called on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

pass element to view:

```
new ProjectItemView({model: tmp, el:'#container'}).render();
```